# SplitContainer Panel Reset scroll on focus

Tags: c#, forms, panel, uisplitviewcontroller

I got split container in my code. I have a problem with it's panel, that panel has got auto scroll. Each time I focus the panel, the panel scrolls get reset.

I so that alot of people got this problem and you can fix it by implementing:

```
override Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl) {
    this.AutoScrollPosition;
}
```

But the problem is that you need to inherit Panel and implement that function in the custom panel. But in my case the panel belongs to the split container and I can not change it.

Comment: One way is to put that custom panel inside the SplitContainer panel.

Comment: How? the panel inside the splitcontainer is readonly, i can not change it

Comment: I didn't say change it.  You just place the custom panel in the SplitContainer panel you want, make it Dock = Fill.  Put all of your other controls inside that custom panel now.  All from the designer.

Comment: oh i get it, ill give it a try, thank you

Comment: Working, thank you very much